# Does Main Thread requires thread object monitor to call the synchronized start() method

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I am trying to understand synchronization in java. There are some synchronized methods in Thread class itself, like start() method, join(millis) method. So, the thread which is starting another thread, requires a thread object monitor to enter inside this start() method?

```
public class Thread implements Runnable {
    public synchronized void start() {
    }
}

class Demo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is under execution");
            }
        },"FirstThread");
        t1.start();
    }
}
```

Does the main thread requires t1 thread object monitor, to enter into synchronized start() method?

Comment: Your question is not well-formed; in Java, objects have monitors, not locks. If you mean to ask "does the main thread have to hold the monitor of the thread in `t1`, then yes, just as `synchronized` indicates.

Comment: The main thread *acquires* the monitor *by* calling the `synchronized start()` method. Nothing else required. But as `start` returns almost immediately it won't hold it for long.

Comment: Hey chrylis, Thanks, I will edit my question.

Comment: So we can say, a thread instance monitor can also be acquired just as similar to any non-thread instance monitor, like shared data structure instance monitor can be acquired by a thread instance to execute its synchronized method or block.

Comment: This is a distinction without a difference. 'Thread instance monitor' and 'non-thread instance monitor' are the same thing: just object monitors.

Comment: FWIW: It is important for `start()` to be synchronized. The author of some weird-ass program _could_, in principle, try to have two different threads both call `t.start()` at the same time for the same `Thread t` instance, and that probably would be a Bad Thing. I can't imagine _why_ anybody would write code that tries to do that, but making `t.start()` a `synchronized()` method prevents it from happening.

Comment: @SolomonSlow " two different threads both call t.start() at the same time for the same Thread t instance"  - it does not make sense to me. Two different threads are two different objects / instances of Thread.

Comment: @c0der, If I'd said, "two different threads both call `q.put(x)` at the same time for the same `ArrayBlockingQueue` instance, `q`, would that make sense? A `Thread` instance is just an object in the same way that an `ArrayBlockingQueue` is just an object.